# Меняется результат выполнения программы при добавлении строки вывода

Tags: c++, c

Добавление в код единственной строки
`cout << "Tickets " << tickets << endl;`
в корне меняет результат выполнения программы.
Почему это происходит?
Программа должна находить минимально возможную сумму обедов, при условии, что если стоимость обеда выше 100, то покупатель получает купон на бесплатный обед.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка 73, Код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
const int N = 100;
const int INF = 1e+9;

void mySort(int (&arr)[N][N], int size, int row) {
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int tmp;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[row][j] > arr[row][j + 1]) {
                tmp = arr[row][j];
                arr[row][j] = arr[row][j + 1];
                arr[row][j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int findMaxInRange(int const (&arr)[N][N], int row, int from, int to) {
    int max = arr[row][from];
    int idx;
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
        if (arr[row][i] > max) {
            max = arr[row][i];
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    return idx;
}

void dupeRows(int (&arr)[N][N], int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = arr[0][j];
        }
    }
}

void arrOutput(int (&arr)[N][N], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int arr[N][N];
    
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 0 || n > N) return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[0][i];
        if (arr[0][i] < 0 || arr[0][i] > 300) return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    mySort(arr, n, 0);
    dupeRows(arr, n);
    
    int ticket_idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[0][i] > 100) {
            ticket_idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    int tickets = n - ticket_idx;
//  cout << "Tickets " << tickets << endl;
    if (tickets != n) {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (tickets == n - ticket_idx) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tickets; j++) {
                    arr[i][findMaxInRange(arr, i, 0, ticket_idx)] = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int j = 0; j < n - ticket_idx - tickets; j++) {
                    arr[i][findMaxInRange(arr, i, ticket_idx, n)] = 0;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < tickets - (n - ticket_idx - tickets); j++) {
                    arr[i][findMaxInRange(arr, i, 0, ticket_idx)] = 0;
                }
            }
            tickets--;
            if (!tickets) break;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                arr[i][findMaxInRange(arr, i, 0, n)] = 0;
            }
            tickets--;
            if (!tickets) break;
        }
    }
    arrOutput(arr, n);
    
    int sum, minsum = INF;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
        if (sum < minsum) minsum = sum;
    }
    
    cout << minsum << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас не смущает то, что компилятор ругается на потенциальное использование неинициализированной переменной? т.е. в программе имеется потенциально неопределенное поведение?...

И оно не потенциальное: например, при ваших входных данных в в `findMaxInRange` переменная `idx` **не** получает никакого определенного значения, и возвращает какой-то мусор, который хранился в этом месте в памяти.

Добавление вывода немного меняет стек, а также и мусор в неинициализированном значении, вот вы и получаете разные результаты.